# using cursor last returned row is repeated

Tags: mysql, cursor

I have a table named as TRY like this....

```
try(name,sal) values('tony',10000),('david',20000),('rony',30000),('sami',40000)
```

Now I'm using cursor in a procedure to show all the values of the salary column through a variable.Doing this I'm trying to make out that hoe a cursor works as I'm new to cursor and I have come to know that cursor fetches every selected row one by one.I'm doing this following code...

```
 delimiter ;;

 create procedure me()

  begin

    declare done int default 0;

    declare var int;

    declare cur cursor for select sal from try;

    declare continue handler for not found set done=1;

  open cur;

    curloop:loop

     if done=1 then

    leave curloop;

     end if;

       fetch cur into var;

       select var;

    end loop;

 close cur;

end;;
```

Using this I'm getting all the values of SAL column correctly but the problem is that it's returning an extra row which is duplicate of the last value of SAL column,i.e. I'm getting the last value repeated.

Please solve my problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the function a little, check `done` just after FETCH operation -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE me()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done int DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE var int;
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT sal FROM try;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  OPEN cur;

curloop:
  LOOP

    FETCH cur INTO var;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE curloop;
    END IF;

    SELECT var;

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur;
END
```